# Send FormData using Jquery-Ajax to C# Web-Api

Tags: c#, jquery

I have the following function:

```
public class UserRequest
{    
    public string RequestMessage { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
}        
public void CreateRequest(UserRequest userRequest)
{
}
```

When I post to this function with the following script the posted image is always null:

```
var requestMessage = document.getElementById("txtReqMessage").value;
var inputFile = document.getElementById("reqphoto");
var imageFile = inputFile.files[0];

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/UserRequest/CreateRequest/",
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: JSON.stringify({                      
        "RequestMessage": requestMessage,
        "Photo": imageFile
     }),
    success: function () {
        alert("Success");
}
```

I read about posting complex data so I changed the script to:

```
var requestMessage = document.getElementById("txtReqMessage").value;
var inputFile = document.getElementById("reqphoto");
var imageFile = inputFile.files[0];    

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("RequestMessage", requestMessage);
formData.append("Photo", imageFile);   

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/UserRequest/CreateRequest/",
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function () {                  
           alert("Success");
       }
});
```

But now something is wrong I get Error 500.

Comment: 500 error means server error, so try to debug your server code

Comment: This is an old thread, but I have to say it - the extra slash at the end of the URL is causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it to this:

```
public void CreateRequest()
        {

            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            var userRequest = new UserRequest
            {                
                RequestMessage = httpRequest.Form["RequestMessage"],
                Photo = httpRequest.Files["RequestPhoto"],

            };                                               
        }



var formData = new FormData();            
formData.append("RequestMessage", requestMessage);
formData.append("RequestPhoto", imageFile);


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/UserRequest/CreateRequest",
   data: formData,      
   processData: false,
   success: function () {
    alert("OK");
   },
   error: function () {
    alert("Error");
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

define the method as web method

```
[WebMethod]
public void CreateRequest(UserRequest userRequest)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read data in a `FormDataCollection`

```
public void CreateRequest(FormDataCollection form)
{

}
```

try changing `contentType` ajax property to

```
contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
```

you are using `false` value that should be used only when you are sending files

Comment: tryied with both scripts: it's empty.

Comment: try with `contentType: 'multipart/form-data',` you are using false that should be used only when you send files